# Custom Post Loop pulling all custom posts, not just one

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

I'm having an issue with a loop pulling every custom post in my template and not the one that has been requested. This can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g45cf.png

Here is the code I'm using to display the custom post:

```
<?php /*Template Name: Game Listing Page */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="content">
    <?php
    $mypost = array( 'post_type' => 'games_database', );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $mypost );
    ?>
    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <header class="entry-header">

                <!-- Display featured image in right-aligned floating div -->
                <div style="float: right; margin: 10px">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( array( 100, 100 ) ); ?>
                </div>

                <!-- Display game information and review score -->
                <strong>Title: </strong><?php the_title(); ?><br />
                <strong>Platform(s): </strong>
                <?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'games_database_game_platform' ,  ' ' ); ?>
                <br />
                <strong>Genre: </strong>
                <?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'games_database_game_genre' ,  ' ' ); ?>
                <br />
                <strong>Publisher: </strong>
                <?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'game_publisher', true ) ); ?>
                <br />
                <strong>Developer: </strong>
                <?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'game_developer', true ) ); ?>
                <br />
                <strong>Review Score: </strong>
                <?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'game_rating', true ) ); ?>
                <br />

            </header>

            <!-- Display movie review contents -->
            <div class="entry-content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
        </article>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I have no idea where I have gone wrong :( Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: I must add this is in single-games_database.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are within the loop already. You don't need to recreate it (by making another WP_Query). Here is your code, with the `$loop` you created removed. This should work perfectly.

```
<?php /*Template Name: Game Listing Page */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="content">
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <header class="entry-header">

                <!-- Display featured image in right-aligned floating div -->
                <div style="float: right; margin: 10px">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( array( 100, 100 ) ); ?>
                </div>

                <!-- Display game information and review score -->
                <strong>Title: </strong><?php the_title(); ?><br />
                <strong>Platform(s): </strong>
                <?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'games_database_game_platform' ,  ' ' ); ?>
                <br />
                <strong>Genre: </strong>
                <?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'games_database_game_genre' ,  ' ' ); ?>
                <br />
                <strong>Publisher: </strong>
                <?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'game_publisher', true ) ); ?>
                <br />
                <strong>Developer: </strong>
                <?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'game_developer', true ) ); ?>
                <br />
                <strong>Review Score: </strong>
                <?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'game_rating', true ) ); ?>
                <br />

            </header>

            <!-- Display movie review contents -->
            <div class="entry-content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
        </article>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

> I'm having an issue with a loop pulling every custom post in my
>   template and not the one that has been requested.

Your query is requesting _every post of the `games_database` type.

```
$mypost = array( 'post_type' => 'games_database', );
```

There is no argument that would restrict that to a single post. You've literally asked for all of them.

However, take a good look at the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).  If this is in `single-games_database.php` you don't need the query at all. The data you need is in the main query. All you need is the Loop, this part:

```
if (have_posts()) {
  while (have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    // echo post data
  }
}
```